# Having requests as side-effects of another request in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following scenario:
I'm firing an HTTP request (using Observables). Now, during this HTTP request, I want to fire two more requests as a side effect. The latter two requests depend on the first request (they should only be fired when the first request is successful).
Also, I don't care about when those two requests come back, they should just run in the background.

I came up with the following code:

```
performRequests(): Observable<any> {
  const firstRequestUrl = 'https://api.example.com/firstRequest';
  const secondRequestUrl = 'https://api.example.com/secondRequest';
  const thirdRequestUrl = 'https://api.example.com/thirdRequest';

  return this.http.get(firstRequestUrl).pipe(
    tap(() => {
      // The following requests will run in the background without
      // affecting the output of the main request.
      this.http.get(secondRequestUrl).subscribe();
      this.http.get(thirdRequestUrl).subscribe();
    }),
  );
}
```

This works. However, as far as I know it's an anti-pattern to fire requests as a side effect in a pipe() operator. We should rather chain them somehow. But, concat() or merge() wouldn't do the trick, because they're waiting for all requests to come back.

So my question is:

1. Is my approach legit?
2. Is there any better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: If you don't care about the results of those requests, why not just put the 2 lines of code before the `return` statement?

Comment: Good point. However, I wrote it wrong in the thread. Actually the two other requests should only be called if the first one is successful, so they're not completely independant. I changed that in the thread above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap):

```
of(1).pipe(
  switchMap(response1 =>
    forkJoin([of(2), of(3)])
      .pipe(map((result) => ({ first: response1, second: result[0], third: result[1] })))))
  .subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
```

just replace of(1), of(2), of(3) with your observables. Also, subscribing in a  observable is an antipattern.

Comment: Yes, that's how I implemented it now. Nice solution, thanks!